# Box2D World.GetBodyList() Returns NULL but World is Clearly Updating Objects

Tags: c++, box2d

Recently implemented the master branch (couldn't get release 2.3.1 to CMake) of Box2D into a project for quick 2D physics and collision detection. Everything is working fine but when I came around to using the "World.GetBodyList()" function it returned NULL. This seems weird because I know that the world is correctly updating the 2 test objects I have created as the dynamic object falls down onto the static object and balances on top.

I only have the 1 world object and it is a static pointer.

```
private:
        inline static b2World* s_world;
```

World Init

```
void Box2DWrapper::Box2DInit(glm::vec2 gravity)
    {
        b2Vec2 gravityVec = { gravity.x, gravity.y };
        s_world = new b2World(gravityVec);
    }
```

How bodies are created.

```
b2Body* Box2DWrapper::CreateRigidbodyBox(glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 halfDimensions, bool isStatic, float objectDensity, float frictionCoefficient, float restitution, int16_t collisionGroup, Layers myCategories, Layers collisionCategories, bool fixedRotation, float angularDampening, float linearDampening, bool fastDynamicBulletCollisionCheck)
    {
        b2BodyDef newBodyDef;
        newBodyDef.position = { position.x, position.y };
        newBodyDef.angularDamping = angularDampening;
        newBodyDef.linearDamping = linearDampening;
        newBodyDef.fixedRotation = fixedRotation;
        newBodyDef.bullet = fastDynamicBulletCollisionCheck;
        if (!isStatic)
            newBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        b2Body* boxBody = s_world->CreateBody(&newBodyDef);
        b2PolygonShape box;
        box.SetAsBox(halfDimensions.x, halfDimensions.y);
        b2FixtureDef boxDef;
        boxDef.shape = &box;
        boxDef.density = objectDensity;
        boxDef.friction = frictionCoefficient;
        boxDef.restitution = restitution;
        boxDef.filter.groupIndex = collisionGroup;
        boxDef.filter.categoryBits = static_cast<uint16_t>(myCategories);
        boxDef.filter.maskBits = static_cast<uint16_t>(collisionCategories);
        boxBody->CreateFixture(&boxDef);
        return boxBody;
    }
```

This returns nullptr.

```
b2Body* current = s_world->GetBodyList();
```

Not sure if this is all the relevant information as I'm not very knowledgeable on Box2D. Please tell me if something is missing.

Comment: CreateBody will put the body in the body list. GetBodyList just returns the pointer to the head of the list. Nothing special. Are you sure you use the same s_world pointer for both things?

Comment: Yeah, all the functions are static and use the same static member s_world, even when stepping through the code and looking at s_world before and after CreateBody is called shows that the m_bodylist variable is NULL the entire time.

Comment: Debug the code. Just step in the library to see what it does. The involved code is quite simple: https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/src/dynamics/b2_world.cpp
CreateBody is at line 115. As you can see, it does add the body to `m_bodyList`, at the front of the list.

Comment: Currently using Box2D as a lib so I can't step through the code, but both before the CreateBody call and after the CreateBody call the s_world pointer's m_bodylist variable reads as NULL. Which would make me feel that it wasn't adding the variable, but the returned pointer is a valid b2Body that is updated and collides. Making me think that the s_world variable does have these bodies.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently using Box2D as a lib so I can't step through the code

That might be the point.

I had the same issue and I had 2 Versions of Box2D installed. One by the system and one in my local folder. I linked to the local version, but used the system headers.
But the GetBodyCount function is inline and somehow didn't matched to the linked version.

So make sure you link to the same library from which you take the header files.
After I changed that I could again use `GetBodyCount()`